# TextField values are equal to "undefined" in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am very new to ReactJs and Material-UI. Therefore I apologize if my question is dumb.

So, I have a file `Main.js` that contains the following lines of code:

```
  handleChange = (name, event) => {
    if(event==null)
      return;
    console.log(event)
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.value
    }, () => {
      console.log("my_num_var",this.state.my_num_var)
      console.log("my_combobox_var",this.state.my_combobox_var)
    });
  };
```

Then, I have `TopControls.js` with the following code:

```
          <Grid item xs={true}>
            <TextField
                name="my_num_var"
                id="my_num_var"
                label="my_num_var"
                onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("my_num_var", event)}
                value={this.props.state.my_num_var}
                type="number"
                className={this.props.styles.textField}
                margin="normal"
                InputProps={{
                    startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(seconds)</InputAdornment>,
                }}
            />
          </Grid>
```

Each time when I change the value of `my_num_var` (TextField), I see `undefined` in console (`console.log("my_num_var",this.state.my_num_var)`).

In the `handleChange` function, the `console.log(event)` outputs:

> SyntheticEvent {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode,
>   nativeEvent: InputEvent, type: "change", target:
>   input#visibility.MuiInputBase-input-269.MuiInput-input-254.MuiInputBase-inputType-272.MuiInput-inpu…,
>   …}

So, basically `event.value` returns nothing. The value is set only if I do `event.target.value`. But in this case, the comboboxes do not work because they need `event.value`. How can I distinguish between the evnts?

The comboboxes work fine with `event.value` and I can see correct values of `my_combobox_var` in console.

```
          <Grid item xs={true}>
            <FormControl
                className={this.props.styles.formControl}
                margin="normal">
                <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="my_combobox_var-label-placeholder">
                    my_combobox_var
                </InputLabel>
                <Select
                    onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("my_combobox_var", event)}
                    className="basic-single"
                    classNamePrefix="select"
                    defaultValue={this.props.state.my_combobox_var}
                    isClearable={this.state.isClearable}
                    isSearchable={this.state.isSearchable}
                    name="my_combobox_var"
                    options={this.t}
                    styles={myStyle}/>
            </FormControl>
          </Grid>
```

I am not sure if the code that I posted above is enough to help. If I should add more details, please let me know. I would appreciate any clues. Thanks.

Comment: I recommend you put this is CodeSandbox or something similar. Easier to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of passing the whole event to `handleChange` you could pass only the value to make it simpler.

Since the text input needs `event.target.value` instead of `event.value` this will allow you to use the same handler for multiple event types.

```js
onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("my_num_var", event.target.value)

onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("my_num_var", event.value)
```

Then just rewrite your handler to expect the value instead of the event:

```js
handleChange = (name, value) => {
  if(value==null)
    return;
  this.setState({
    [name]: value
  },
...
```

Comment: thanks. in this case the combobox does not work properly.